# DocuSign: Override Account settings for reminder via API

Tags: docusignapi

We built a UI in react which is triggering envelope creation based on PDFs in our application, which are linked to already existing DocuSign templates by using composite templates. So a user has just to enter recipient details and "submit". The pdf is replacing a placeholder in the DS template and the envelope is submitted with recipient details via the rest API.

Now users asked to switch on individual reminders, which is not possible via webportal as we deactivated "Allow senders to override account defaults" on account level and did not switched it on on the DS templates. Background is, that various use cases are served by one DS template and they all have very diverse requirments on when reminder are required and what frequency is required. So as of now, no reminders are sent out of the account at all.

Unfortunately we are not allowed to switch this on account level due to compliance reasons, as end user can do things which we can not control.

We now try to add this as a feature in our application via API and ran into issues.

On https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-reminders-and-expiration-to-an-envelope it is stated, that to enable reminder **for webportal** users, the setting on account level has to be switched on: “Allow senders to override account defaults".

It obviously also influences **API usage**, as without switched on, the reminder cannot be activated via the API user, it ran into errors.

On the above page it is also said: "You can still override these values using the eSignature API, even if the checkbox is not set."

Now I am trying to figure out, what would be required to do this. Side note, the API user does not have administrative rights, he acts as a normal user...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the notification object in your API call to use the account defaults - if that object isn't set, the API will default to its own  reminder and expiration default settings, which is no reminders and expiration after 180 days.

You can add the notification object in your envelope main body:

"notification": {
"useAccountDefaults": "true"
}

Here's the article showing the notification object and how to define it that should help: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-trenches-reminders-expirations